# Add Click handler, and Cancel intervals with clearIntervals

Tags: jquery, click, setinterval, clearinterval

I added the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` to see if my click handler would work and it does. How can I add the click handler to cancel the animation? How can I cancel intervals with the clearInterval function?

```js
var offset = 0;
var direction = "left";
var moveHeading = function() {
  if (direction === "left") {
    $('#heading').offset({
      left: offset
    });
    offset += 2;
    if (offset > 400) {
      direction = "down";
      offset = 0;
    }
  } else if (direction === "down") {
    $('#heading').offset({
      top: offset
    });
    offset += 2;
    if (offset > 400) {
      direction = "right";

    }
  } else if (direction === "right") {
    $('#heading').offset({
      left: offset
    });
    offset -= 2;
    if (Math.abs(offset) <= 0) {
      direction = "up";
      offset = 0;
    }
  } else if (direction === "up") {
    $('#heading').offset({
      top: offset
    });
    offset -= 2;
    if (Math.abs(offset) > 200) {
      direction = "left";
      offset = 0;
    }
  }
};

setInterval(moveHeading, 30);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#heading").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(3000).fadeIn(3000);
  })
})

clearInterval(moveHeading);
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Hola mi gente!! Como esta?</h1>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the animation on click of `#heading` you need to store the id returned from the `setInterval()` call then provide that to the `clearInterval()` call within the click event handler. Try this:

```js
var offset = 0;
var direction = "left";
var moveHeading = function() {
  if (direction === "left") {
    $('#heading').offset({
      left: offset
    });
    offset += 2;
    if (offset > 400) {
      direction = "down";
      offset = 0;
    }
  } else if (direction === "down") {
    $('#heading').offset({
      top: offset
    });
    offset += 2;
    if (offset > 400) {
      direction = "right";

    }
  } else if (direction === "right") {
    $('#heading').offset({
      left: offset
    });
    offset -= 2;
    if (Math.abs(offset) <= 0) {
      direction = "up";
      offset = 0;
    }
  } else if (direction === "up") {
    $('#heading').offset({
      top: offset
    });
    offset -= 2;
    if (Math.abs(offset) > 200) {
      direction = "left";
      offset = 0;
    }
  }
};

let interval = setInterval(moveHeading, 30);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#heading").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(3000).fadeIn(3000);
    clearInterval(interval);
  })
})
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Hola mi gente!! Como esta?</h1>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rory McCrossan for your help, I greatly appreciate it.